# How to keep the distance to one button , if the size of the label changes ? Objective-c

Tags: ios, ios7, ios-simulator

It is necessary to save one distance between label and buttons . But the size of the label changes . How can i do this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRE17.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dXwJ.png

Comment: Have you tried autolayout?

Comment: No. Tell us more about it . I have a quiz and each question has a different text. Set an example in this case. Please.

Comment: It's quite a large subject, and Stack Overflow is not the place for a tutorial. Have a read of the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ , try and implement it yourself and then ask a specific question if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With auto-layout you can define the rules for your graphics. It can solve your problem. You can find also a lot of tutorial in the web. Search for "ios auto layout tutorial"

Comment: Please show an example related to my problem .
Or tell us how to solve my problem by using autolayout.

Comment: I suggest to look here http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: did you see the tutorial ? Is there well done.. I'm sure you can find the solution for your problem.

Comment: is very strange because auto-layout is exactly created also for your kind of problem. Read all the tutorial or apple documentation and try to play with auto layout directly in your project.